# Referenced type is only valid for encoded SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to generate C# proxy class from wsdl file by using svcutil. 
But I get a lot errors:
Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='Feed']/wsdl:portType[@name='FeedPortType']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='Feed']/wsdl:portType[@name='FeedPortType']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='Feed']/wsdl:binding[@name='FeedBinding']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='Feed']/wsdl:binding[@name='FeedBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='Feed']/wsdl:service[@name='Feed']/wsdl:port[@name='FeedPort']

I have discovered that reason way I get this error is next:
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

```
 <xsd:complexType name="gameWST">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="game" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="amountWagers" type="xsd:float"/>
   <xsd:element name="amountSettlements" type="xsd:float"/>
   <xsd:element name="amountTips" type="xsd:float"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="gameWSTArray">
  <xsd:complexContent>
   <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:gameWST[]"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

Is it possible to fix it?